# Sublime Text 3 Indent and shortcode conflict

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

When I write JS code I need to insert indents (with tabs, not space) between key and value, but ST3 inserts shortcode, but there it is not necessary:

```
'name':my_var,

'name'key: "value", my_var,
```

How can I resolve this problem without disable all shortcodes?